# Autoencoders for Dimensionality reduction of mixed data

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder, dimensionality-reduction

The task is to use Autoencoders as a dimensionality reduction technique, but I have data of continuous and categorical(nominal and ordinal) type and I am confused as to how to apply the autoencoders on this type of data? Which Loss function should I choose?

Comment: Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Here you post abstract question which people will likely delete rather answer. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will keep that in mind. However, regarding this question I asked, I tried researching and couldn't really find the solution. Hence asked it in that fashion.